# Setting up multiple applications on one server within directory paths

Tags: routing, port, node.js, directory

I am working with node.js and I am trying to figure out a way to have a rather different server configuration.

I would like to have three "apps" run.

- index
- app1
- app2

Index can run on port 80, and would assume the root domain name `domain.com`.

I want `app1` and `app2` to appear `domain.com/app1` and `domain.com/app2` respectively.

I was thinking it might be possible for `app1` and `app2` to run on different ports (e.g. 81, 82) and somehow mask `domain.com/app1` over `domain.com:81`.

Is there anyway to do this configuration?

Full disclosure, I added this question (worded very differently) to [stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088165/multiple-express-apps-share-same-domain-in-different-directories) and I've been told that the sub-domain route is the easiest, and I understand, but I would really like to try to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

HAPROXY was my solution. Its really great at doing exactly what I need.